# What is the Theoretical Limit of Entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

We can entangle sub-particles and particles. I believe we can entangle some atoms, but could we theoretically entangle molecules and, to just throw the ball out there, even two big objects (like ATM machines)? Maybe our Universe is entangled already. I realize that entanglement does become harder, but I'd like to think in a sense of strictly is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${\cal H}$ be the state space of the universe.

For any given decomposition $D$ of the form ${\cal H}={\cal H}_1\otimes {\cal H_2}$, let $U(D)=\lbrace h_1\otimes h_2 \vert h_i\in H_i\rbrace$.  Then the complement of $U(D)$ is easily seen to be open and dense in ${\cal H}$.

Now at least if there are a finite number of particles in the Universe, there are a finite number of relevant decompositions, so if we let $U$  be the union of all the $U(D)$, then the complement of $U$  is also open and dense in ${\cal H}$.  This makes it seem very likely that the actual state of the universe usually lies in that complement, which is to say that at most times, it should be impossible to divide the Universe into *any* two subsystems that are unentangled with each other.

Comment: Thank you, you even stated the answer as a formula that accounts for the entire universe